# How do I restrict the Android keyboard presented to a user to Latin?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an application that requires that the user enter an ASCII password between dec 32 and 126. This means that only a latin character and number keyboard is valid for editing. However, when I launch my edittext, a cyrillic keyboard is presented to the user.

My question is, how do I ensure that only a latin keyboard is presented to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your xml:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" />
```

Comment: This approach will restrict the valid character set, but it will not influence the keyboard displayed. If I use this approach, the values will simply not be propagated to the preview.

Comment: Have you tried it? The inputType is what define the keys the keyboard should display, it's now just filtering. However, if it still shows a cyrilic keyboard, then I cannot help. Are you using SwiftKey?

Comment: I am using the standard Android keyboard. No this approach doesn't resolve the issue I am encountering.

Comment: In my understanding that's not possible then, since you have to actually change your language in the keyboard settings (at least for SwiftKey). It doesn't happen at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to force IME to a certain language/character set.  However, if you set your EditText to be type password, most software keyboards will limit itself to ASCII + number.  That's the closest you will get without writing your own input method.

```
<EditText
 android:password="true"
 ...
 />
```

Comment: This approach doesn't restrict the keyboard shown to LatinIME.

Comment: As I said, you cannot force an IME to show up.  Some devices does not even have LatinIME installed.  If you want to be in absolute control, you will have to write your own input view. A "View" within your app, not a IME because user can switch out to different IME.