# How to detect cyrillic text in edit text?

Tags: android, character-encoding, android-edittext, cyrillic

I need to protect entering cyrillic text in my application.

Is there some method how can I detect which encoding of the entered symbols in the editText?

Comment: you could check the keyboard's language

Comment: where i must put it?
inside textWatcher or where?

Comment: please explain your use case in detail. depending upon your use case you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30631069/1529129) or have a regex in place which can be checked with text watcher.

Comment: @RahulTiwari, thanks :)
half an hour find this solution )

Comment: @LudoBagman still question remains, what were you trying to do :)

Comment: @RahulTiwari, allow user to enter only latin and special characters

Comment: @LudoBagman: you can apply filter according to your needs.

Comment: @Blackbelt: Hello buddy, As far as I know, even if the language is not containing cyrillic characters, user will be able to insert such characters anyhow. i.e.: copy-paste. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes of course, @MehulJoisar

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You need to apply [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) on your `EditText`.

**Example:**

Set filter on your `EditText`

```
etNonCyrillic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNonCyrillic );
etNonCyrillic .setFilters(new InputFilter[]{cyrillicFilter});
```

Implementation `cyrillicFilter`:

```
    public static InputFilter cyrillicFilter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        boolean keepOriginal = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char c = source.charAt(i);
            if (!isCyrillicCharacter(c))
            {
                sb.append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                keepOriginal = false;
            }
        }
        if (keepOriginal)
            return null;
        else {
            if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return sb;
            }           
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private boolean isCyrillicCharacter(char c)
    {
        boolean isPriorToKitkat = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<19;
        UnicodeBlock block = UnicodeBlock.of(c);
        boolean isCyrillicCharacter = (block.equals(UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC) || block.equals(UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC_SUPPLEMENTARY) || (isPriorToKitkat?false:(block.equals(UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC_EXTENDED_A) || block.equals(UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC_EXTENDED_B))));
        return isCyrillicCharacter;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Kotlin to prevent users from saving details with cyrillic and greek letters

```
 fun isOnlyLatinLetters(string: String?): Boolean {
    if (string == null) return false
    return !(CYRILLIC.containsMatchIn(string)
      || GREEK.containsMatchIn(string))
  }

  private val CYRILLIC = Pattern.compile("[Ѐ-ӿ]").toRegex()
  private val GREEK = Pattern.compile("[Ͱ-Ͽ]").toRegex()
```